# Hints, with a bit of love ! (5)

Tags: wordplay, cryptic-clues, humor

Inspired by [this page](http://www.funny-jokes.com/months/funny_anagrams.htm) and some other pages, I made some cryptic clues.

1. Start growing before rain!
2. Needles , before first sewer! (8)
3. Dirty, dirty room! (9)
4. Eleven plus two makes... (6,4,3)
5. Dust, head in power! (6)
6. Bad astronomers!! (2,4,5)
7. Messes up the classroom! (12)
8. Lived Badly! (5)
9. Sadly, cash lost in 'em! (4,8)
10. Real fun? Wrong! (7)

Hint:

> Read the title and the tags.

Comment: deef evig esaelP

Comment: Is the bad punctuation and English intentional?

Comment: @S.S.Anne ProbabIy no.

Comment: @Scratch---Cat Don't forget to accept if hexomino was correct.

Answer (score 11):

1. Start growing before rain!

   > Grain = G + rain
2. Needles, before first sewer! (8)

   > Needless = Needles + s
3. Dirty, dirty room! (9)

   > Dormitory = anagram of "dirty room"
4. Eleven plus two makes... (6,4,3)

   > Twelve plus one = anagram of "eleven plus two"
5. Dust, head in power! (6)

   > Powder = Pow(d)er
6. Bad astronomers!! (2,4,5)

   > No more stars = anagram of "astronomers"
7. Messes up the classroom! (12)

   > Schoolmaster = anagram of "the classroom"
8. Lived Badly! (5)

   > Devil = anagram of "lived"
9. Sadly, cash lost in 'em! (4,8)

   > Slot Machines = anagram of "cash lost in 'em"
10. Real fun? Wrong! (7)

    > Funeral = anagram of "real fun"

Title

> Clues = C(l)ues (not sure about this one)

Comment: Please give feed back and suggestions to my clues in the comments. I'm not good at creating cryptic clues. I'm pretty bad at *solving* cryptics too (sometimes the anagram fodder is too long). @deusovi

Comment: @Scratch---Cat So, for me, a few of these don't work entirely especially in terms of the literal interpretation. I don't really understand the interpretation of 5 (only the wordplay) and the interpretation of 7 seems to be almost the opposite of the answer. I don't know if they all fully qualify as cryptic clues (6 and 9 are probably the best for me) but maybe you could style them differently, call them something else?

Comment: Perhaps for 7, "Organises the classroom" seems to work both ways. For 5, isn't dust basically the same as the answer (thinking dust/dirt)?

Comment: @MatthewJensen Yes, regarding 5, it's the "head in power" bit which doesn't really work for me from the &lit perspective (only in the wordplay). I agree with your assessment of 7, would work a lot better.

Comment: Help me solve these clues: http://scratch.mit.edu/discuss/topic/340885/?page=2#post-3820732 @hexomino